# Which direction/constellation is the James Webb is headed towards

Tags: james-webb-telescope

I am curious to know at which direction can we can see James Webb Space Telescope.

If you know at which direction/constellation is James Webb going, dont mind it sharing.

Note: By the word **see** I did not mean to see it by naked eye

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Which direction/constellation is the James Webb is headed towards

vs

> I am curious to know at which direction can we can see James Webb Space Telescope.

Since it's not traveling in a straight line directly away from you, where it's headed towards and where we would see it are different directions. [JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/) can give you the coordinates where it will appear, either from the center of the Earth or from your location.

Here are a few lines as seen from Paris, France at midnight UTC, holler if you need more assistance using Horizons!

```
                         RA           DEC        Azimuth    Elevation  
 UTC date & time       h  m  s     d   m  s       (deg)      (deg)
2021-Dec-26 00:00     05 04 13.83 -03 01 57.6   205.577701  35.114853
2021-Dec-27 00:00     05 42 13.50 -01 13 07.5   195.730539  38.840861
2021-Dec-28 00:00     05 55 17.07 -00 41 18.1   192.933979  39.728774
2021-Dec-29 00:00     06 02 51.97 -00 23 19.3   191.812727  40.149789
2021-Dec-30 00:00     06 08 05.43 -00 10 18.7   191.432930  40.404420
2021-Dec-31 00:00     06 12 02.11 +00 00 34.8   191.462469  40.582398
```

Comment: yeah you are right, i will mind in next time, thx for the suggestion!

Comment: You could add a description of the final orbit - circling the "midnight point" right opposite to the Sun at a distance of about 14° to 30°.

Comment: @asdfex excellent idea! Okay I'll try some plotting when I get that ever-elusive round tuit.

Comment: @asdfex I've just asked [How can I find the old reference orbit for JWST (from 2014) and get AltAz positions from Earth without learning Spice? Can Horizons do it? Can Python?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57417/12102)

Answer (score 5):

In general, Webb will be in view every night for most people on Earth, weather permitting. It will generally visit constellations near the ecliptic ( the zodiac and beyond), since it expected to be in a very wide Lissajous orbit around L2.

Since the sunshield is so large (the size of a tennis court), it may even be visible in telescopes. I don't know how easy that is, but one manufacturer is encouraging people to try: [Here’s How to Spot the JWST with Your Telescope! - Unistellar](https://unistellaroptics.com/observe-jwst/)j

For precise directions from a given place and time, visit https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/, "edit" the "target" object and specify "JWST", and pick a time range which isn't too far in the future. For a geocentric viewer, that puts it in [Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion%20(constellation)) early on, and [Monoceros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoceros) after that, ranging between 394,000 and 1,351,000 km away:

```
 Date__(UT)__HR:MN     R.A._____(ICRF)_____DEC             delta      deldot  Cnst
**********************************************************************************
 2021-Dec-28 00:00     05 55 42.03 +00 00 52.7  3.9360502697E+05   1.1421383   Ori
 2022-Jan-02 00:00     06 18 02.74 +00 42 01.9  7.5363851034E+05   0.6371597   Ori
 2022-Jan-07 00:00     06 27 49.01 +01 28 43.3  9.8349587954E+05   0.4463153   Mon
 2022-Jan-12 00:00     06 35 59.67 +02 24 55.9  1.1486661539E+06   0.3247396   Mon
 2022-Jan-17 00:00     06 44 03.89 +03 27 03.4  1.2679857110E+06   0.2312046   Mon
 2022-Jan-22 00:00     06 52 07.65 +04 35 18.6  1.3514567243E+06   0.1589372   Mon
```

**Update**: See [photo of JWST in Orion by @Skysurfer77x](https://twitter.com/Skysurfer77x/status/1475946879456366594) - amazing!

Comment: You got a good one thanks for the links that you shared I will definitely try it at my home!

Comment: just asked: [Help me understand these tweeted images of JWST moving through Orion!](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57454/12102)